# Non-zero homogeneous polynomials can be considered as sections of $\mathcal{O}(k)$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, line-bundles

This is a passage from a complex geometry lecture notes

> Any homogeneous polynomial $s \in \mathbb{C}[z_0,...,z_n]_k$ with degree $k$ defines a linear map $(\mathbb{C}^{n+1})^{\otimes k} \to \mathbb{C}$. This gives rise to a holomorphic map $\mathbb{P}^n \times (\mathbb{C}^{n+1})^{\otimes k} \to \mathbb{C}$ which is linear on any fibre of the projection to $\mathbb{P}^n$. The restriction to $\mathcal{O}(-k)$ thus provides a holomorphic section of $\mathcal{O}(k)$.

I need some help understanding this result. Why does a homogeneous polynomial $s \in \mathbb{C}[z_0,...,z_n]_k$ with degree $k$ give us a linear map $(\mathbb{C}^{n+1})^{\otimes k} \to \mathbb{C}$ and secondly why does this give rise to a holomorphic map $\mathbb{P}^n \times (\mathbb{C}^{n+1})^{\otimes k} \to \mathbb{C}$?

It seems that the author is skipping over some important details here.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3506455/homogeneous-polynomials-of-degree-k-provide-holomorphic-sections-of-mathcal and now combine this with the fact that the projection map $\mathbb{P}^n\times(\mathbb{C}^{n+1})^{\otimes k}\to(\mathbb{C}^{n+1})^{\otimes k}$ is holomorphic.